# R All possible sub-combinations

Tags: r, combinations

I have some data that look like this:

```
basin <- c("Volta","Seine","Limpopo")
c1 <- c("BEN","BEL","SA")
c2 <- c("BURK","FRA","MOZ")
c3 <- c("IVC","LUX","ZIM")
c4 <- c("GHA","NA","BOTS")
c5 <- c("MALI","NA","NA")
c6 <- c("TOGO","NA","NA")
df <- data.frame(basin, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)

    basin  c1  c2  c3   c4   c5   c6
1   Volta BEN BUR IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
2   Seine BEL FRA LUX   NA   NA   NA
3 Limpopo  SA MOZ ZIM BOTS   NA   NA
```

Each basin has k countries. For example in the first row, I need to generate all combinations of 5 countries, all combinations of 4 countries, and so on. The second row I need to generate all combinations of 2 countries and third row all combinations of 3 countries and 2countries. Then I would like to add these subsets as new rows in the data.

I tried to use this function:

```
    allSubs <- function(x, k) {
  if(k > length(x)) stop('k > length(x)')
  if(choose(length(x), k)==1){
    list(as.vector(combn(x, k)))
  } else {
    cbn <- combn(x, k)
    lapply(seq(ncol(cbn)), function(i) cbn[,i])
  }
}
```

However, I can only get it to work if I feed it the data like this:

```
allSubs(c('BEN','BURK','IVC','GHA','MALI','TOGO'),4)
```

But I really need it to iterate through the rows in the data frame. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution with data as follows (your input data is still a bit problematic and I modified the code to generate the correct data):

```
basin <- c("Volta","Seine","Limpopo")
c1 <- c("BEN","BEL","SA")
c2 <- c("BURK","FRA","MOZ")
c3 <- c("IVC","LUX","ZIM")
c4 <- c("GHA",NA,"BOTS")
c5 <- c("MALI",NA,NA)
c6 <- c("TOGO",NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(basin, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    basin  c1   c2  c3   c4   c5   c6
1   Volta BEN BURK IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
2   Seine BEL  FRA LUX <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 Limpopo  SA  MOZ ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>

apply(df[, 2:7], 1, function(x) {l <- x[!is.na(x)]; sapply(seq(1:(length(l)-1)), function(y) combn(l, y))})
```

Result will be various sub combinations of each country code per row. Hope this helps. Of course, you can split up the 'inline' function(s) I used to external functions that you invoke in the `apply` call.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I adjusted the data in the original post to include NAs (and also showed how I created it). I am not very good at working with data in R so that was my mistake. I need it in that format because this is only a small sample of the data while I am trying to get code to work.

Comment: I edited the answer to fit the modified data. Don't know if this is what you are looking for as output as you did not specify the expected output.

Comment: That is great! Two questions: how would I adjust it to not list combinations of one? I changed it to `sapply(seq(2:(length(l)-1))`, but it did not do what I thought it would. Also, how would I get the combination outputs back into the data frame? Or into any data frame that could order the combination output by basin?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want for a **fixed** amount of combinations, not "n" number of combinations.

```
expand.grid(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)
```

I suggest putting c1, c2, c3.....cn in a list using this.

```
list <- mget(ls(pattern='^c\\d+'))
```

This creates a list based off objects in your envrionment that start with the letter "c", title your datasets to be more specific to avoid it intaking other objects that start with "c" or anything you specify it by. So just replace c with the start of the names of the objects you are referring to.

```
expand.grid(list)

    c1  c2   c3   c4  c5   c6
1   BEN BURK IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
2   BEL BURK IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
3    SA BURK IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
4   BEN  FRA IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
5   BEL  FRA IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
6    SA  FRA IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
7   BEN  MOZ IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
8   BEL  MOZ IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
9    SA  MOZ IVC  GHA MALI TOGO
10  BEN BURK LUX  GHA MALI TOGO

...............................

723  SA BURK ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>
724 BEN  FRA ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>
725 BEL  FRA ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>
726  SA  FRA ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>
727 BEN  MOZ ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>
728 BEL  MOZ ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>
729  SA  MOZ ZIM BOTS <NA> <NA>
```

If you are wondering how to assign objects similiar names in a series, I suggest toying around with the **assign** function.

Here's a example.

```
for (i in 2:ncol(df)-1) {
  assign(paste("Combo",i,sep=""), df[, i+1])
}
```

Just food for thought if you don't like hard coding the variable names.

For the list of all possible group of 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s, 6s....ns, I will have to think about this. Will get back to this soon.

I'm thinking some combination of the allPerms function the vegan package, and group_by package in dplyr should do the trick, but I will have to see.

Comment: ah, i see the issue...will have to experiment around...my bad